# send and recv back and forth

Tags: c, sockets, send, recv

I'm trying to implement a very simple tcp server/client which should do this:
S:listens on port
C:connects
S:send "hello, type the password"
C:gets message, sends password
S:answers "right" or "wrong" in case of right/wrong password from the client.

I hope this is clear.

How would I do this in C? I used Beej's Guide to sockets programming and just changed the 
Code a bit. Server:

```
i = send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0);
printf("send returned %d\n", i);

char* buf;
recv(new_fd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE - 1, 0);
buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE] = '\0';
if (!strncmp(buf, "lol", 3)) //the pw is lol
{
   send(new_fd, "right", 11, 0); 
   printf("logged in\n");
}
else
{
   // ...as above...
}
close(new_fd);
```

The Client works correspondingly. 
Can't I mix recvs and sends? Neither the send after the recv on the client-side works, nor does the recv after the send on the server-side. 
What am I missing?
Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: In what way does it not work?  The code that you posted looks like it'll crash when it gets to the `recv` call, because `buf` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: Ahhh. You're totally right. I didn't give it an appropriate size. Thats what you meant by invalid, right? Anyway, works fine now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know what is not working, make it a little bit clear, but I'll give you a couple of advices, first you should reserve memory for your buf, something like buf = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*MAX_BUF_SIZE); After that, don't trust the data inside of the buffer and use memclear before send and recv

Comment: @izuel There is no need to clear buffers. It's a complete waste of time. You only have to be aware how much data you've actually received.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* buf;
```

Instant SIGSEGV when you use this. Make it

```
char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
```

Then:

```
recv(new_fd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE - 1, 0);
buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE] = '\0';
```

You're ignoring the value returned by `recv().`

```
int count = recv(new_fd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE - 1, 0);
if (count == 0)
{
    // peer has closed the connection
    close(new_fd);
    return;
}
if (count == -1)
{
    // I/O error
    perror("recv");
    close(new_fd);
    return;
}
// All good: you received 'count' bytes
buf[count] = '\0';
```

Note that `count,` if positive, may be anything between `1` and `MAX_BUF_SIZE-1.` The `recv()` function isn't obliged to fill your buffer, receive an entire 'message', etc.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it now, this was the problem to not allocate space for my char pointer. For the sake of simplicity I left the checking out of my above code. I do that on my own code. It works fine now. Thanks. There was no segfault, however. Why wouldn't my program segfault? Because I didn't leave my memory space the OS gave the process?